# How to tell if a Google Calendar event is recurring (i.e. part of a series)?

Tags: google-apps-script

If I get all of the events from a Google calendar using Apps Script, how can I tell if the event is recurring or not?

For example I can get an array of events using:

```
function test() {
  var startTime = new Date(2019, 8, 1)
  var endTime = new Date()
  var c = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()[0]
  var a = c.getEvents(startTime, endTime)
  a.forEach(function(e) {
    var id = e.getId()
    Logger.log(id)
    var b = c.getEventSeriesById(id)
    if (b !== null) {
      Logger.log('got series')
    }
  })
  return

} // test()
```

But getEventSeriesById() returns an event series regardless of whether the event has one or not.

Comment: What happens if you use the method `getTitle()` on that returned event series that was never actually created?

Answer (score 3):

I eventually resorted to using the Advanced Calendar service which has a "recurrence" property in the event object only for recurring events:

```
function test2() {
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(CALENDAR_NAME).items
  events.forEach(function(event) {
    if (event.hasOwnProperty('recurrence')) {
      Logger.log('Recurring event: ' + event.id)
    } else {
      Logger.log('None Recurring event: ' + event.id)    
    }
  })
}
```